# subgroup problem in abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a given nonempty set. $S(A)$ is a group with respect to mapping composition. For a fixed element $a$ in $A$, let $H_{a}$ denote the set of all $f \in S(A)$ such that $f(a) = a$. Prove that $H_{a}$ is a subgroup of $S(A)$.

Comment: I don't suppose you have any thoughts of your own?

Comment: You haven't said what $S(A)$ is. What have you tried? Do you know how to check whether something is a subgroup? For example, you have to check that a product of two elements of $H_a$ is in $H_a$. What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry. Let $S(A)$ denote the set of all permutations on $A$

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like homework, so only a hint. If $f,g \in H_a$, what is $f(g(a))$? Similarly, what is $f^{-1}(a)$? What does this tell you about $f \circ g$ and $f^{-1}$?